# 12K document in single document library!

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search

One of my customer is using a custom DMS in which they store all documents, of all projects and departments etc, at single location with metadata tagged with each document and use a search/filter page to get the document.

Currently there are more than 12k document in this DMS.

Now they are planning to migrate this DMS on SharePoint Online but want same structure of DMS, means they will upload from one single location and retrieve from on single search page.  They want to save all the 10000 document in one single library and their pace of document is 500 new documents each month.

Can any one suggest is it ok to save all document (12k in this case) in one Document library. or Should I segregate these on some metadata basis into different library.

Answer (score 0):

It is Okay to save this is one document library. but not the best way though.

SharePoint Document Library will be supporting up to 30,000,000 per library.

in Microsoft own words

> You can create very large document libraries by nesting folders, or using standard views and site hierarchy. This value may vary depending on how documents and folders are organized, and by the type and size of documents stored.

Alternative is that you can create Document Center site that is suggested as best alternative.

> SharePoint offers many features for managing content, and it scales well. If you have hundreds or thousands of documents, videos, and so on that you have to manage, consider using a Document Center site template (included with SharePoint by default). This template is optimized for large-scale document management. It can save time and help you be more efficient, SharePoint also includes the Document Center site template. Key features such as document versions, document IDs, document sets, metadata navigation, and content types are built in to the template for you.

Read this Office support document to know more about Document center site templates and it's features and advantages.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-Document-Center-site-06096070-d83f-45b8-b02d-ec7a4cf85cac

Comment: thanks john for your input, have you use a document library with this much number of documents !

Comment: We have a document center site for such large number of documents (more than lakhs of documents and growing) . That is being used for knowledge base.

Comment: what is the maximum no. of document with within a single library !

Comment: Please read my answer, I mentioned SharePoint Document Library will be supporting up to 30,000,000 per library

Comment: Should my answer help you, please upvote /accept answers. That will encourage more users to contribute to your questions.

Comment: That i already knew what MS says about the threshold of a library.  My concern to raise the question was to get know if someone has handled this big no. of document in a single library without any technical challenge ...

Comment: That's why we gone for this document center site, pleas explore and you'll eventually know the advantages of it. It'll help you especially when you expect to have such huge numbers of documents.